# Force + Drag + Zoom : freeze after few seconds

Tags: javascript, d3.js

First, I'm quite new in D3.
I'm trying to implement different behaviors in a single D3 graph, using these examples :

- [Drag + Zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708)
- Force-directed Graph

But my graph freezes after few seconds and I don't understand why...

Here is my code : http://jsfiddle.net/blt909/aVhd8/20/ [WORKING FINE VERSION]

```
 var margin = {top: -5, right: -5, bottom: -5, left: -5};
    var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 400- margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-200)
        .linkDistance(50)
        .size([width + margin.left + margin.right, height + margin.top + margin.bottom]);

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 10])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(function(d) { return d; })
        .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("dragend", dragended);


    var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
        .call(zoom);

    var rect = svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("pointer-events", "all");

    var container = svg.append("g");

            force
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .links(graph.links)
                .start();

            var tooltip = d3.select("body")
                .append("foreignObject")
                .append("xhtml:div")
                .attr("id", "tooltip")
                .style("position", "absolute")
                .style("z-index", "10")
                .style("color", "#eeeeee")
                .style("visibility", "hidden")
                .text("");

    var link = container.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "links")
                    .selectAll(".link")
        .data(graph.links)
                    .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

    var node = container.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "nodes")
                    .selectAll(".node")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
                    .call(drag);

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.weight * 2+ 12; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(1/d.rating); });


            force.on("tick", function() {
                link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

                node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
            });

            var linkedByIndex = {};
            graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
                linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
            });

            function isConnected(a, b) {
                return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index];
            }

    node.on("mouseover", function(d){

                    node.classed("node-active", function(o) {
                        thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? true : false;
                        this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                        return thisOpacity;
                    });

                    link.classed("link-active", function(o) {
                        return o.source === d || o.target === d ? true : false;
                    });

                    d3.select(this).classed("node-active", true);
                    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
                            .duration(750)
                            .attr("r", (d.weight * 2+ 12)*1.5);
            })

    .on("mouseout", function(d){

                    node.classed("node-active", false);
                    link.classed("link-active", false);

                    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
                            .duration(750)
                            .attr("r", d.weight * 2+ 12);
            });


    function dottype(d) {
      d.x = +d.x;
      d.y = +d.y;
      return d;
    }

    function zoomed() {
      container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }

    function dragstarted(d) {
      d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();

      d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);

//ADDING force.start(); HERE SOLVES THE ISSUE
 force.start();
    }

    function dragged(d) {

      d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);

    }

    function dragended(d) {

      d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Works fine for me. What do you mean by "freeze"?

Comment: When I drag circles a couple of times, they became undraggable but zoom behavior remains...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting force.start(); inside dragstarted function stops freezing.

```
function dragstarted(d) {
      d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
      d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
      force.start();
};
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuckovic/6JGE2/)